# Firebase Admin SDk not working from backend Java

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

I am trying to push message in firebase real time database through            firebase admin sdk java, but my problem is that the same code works 
           fine on my local system and I am able to push message successfully 
           in database but its not working in testing environment and testing 
           environment is AWS server with ubuntu installed in 
           it, on researching it on google I am not able to find solution for 
           this?

```
public static class User {

    public String date_of_birth;
    public String full_name;
    public String nickname;

    public User(String date_of_birth, String full_name) {
        // ...
    }

    public User(String date_of_birth, String full_name, String nickname) {
        // ...
    }

}

Map<String, User> users = new HashMap<>();
users.put("alanisawesome", new User("June 23, 1912", "Alan Turing"));
users.put("gracehop", new User("December 9, 1906", "Grace Hopper"));
```

Code for making connection is.....

```
  FileInputStream serviceAccount;
  FirebaseOptions options;
  try {
        serviceAccount = new FileInputStream("/********.json");
                options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                           .setDatabaseUrl("https://myDatabaseUrl")                           
       .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
                          .build();
                FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);

                flagForConnectionWithFirebase=true;
                LOGGER.info("Options are:: "+options);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }                                                         
    final FirebaseDatabase database = 
                           FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference(url);
    String key=ref.push().getKey();
    ref.child(key).setValueAsync(users);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Are you getting any errors? How is your code deployed? Is it part of a webapp, a command-line application or something else?

Comment: Deployed it as a standalone application and i run my java class through command line, its not pushing message on testing environment but when I run the same code on my local by command the code works fine and push message to database. One more question is it necessary that SSL port to be open to communicate with firebase, because till now i found that to be the issue

Answer (score 0):

After a long search I found that the server was not sync with centralised time zone. post doing that code run successfully on testing environment as well.

Comment: Where can one chech that?

Comment: Check your server time and sync it with centralised time zone

Comment: that case should return an error "Failed to get token: Error: Error refreshing access token:     invalid_grant (Invalid JWT: Token must be a short-lived token and in a reasonable timeframe)"

Answer (score 0):

I found what seems to be quite a common problem that nobody cares to resolve and it is that there an dependency conflict in one of the Firebase dependencies

```
<groupId>com.vaadin.external.google</groupId>
<artifactId>android-json</artifactId>
```

It can be solved by excluding the dependency from Spring Boot Test and the pring-boot-configuration-processor. Now I am having some problems when running test, still cannot tell if they are related.